# Associate an object with Marker (google map v2)

Tags: android, android-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In my app I have some objects that have their location displayed on the map using markers.
The problem is that the only way I've found to handle marker clicks is

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new ... {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
       // how to get the object associated to marker???
    }
})
```

In other words I get the Marker object while the only interface that I have allows me to set just MarkerOptions.

Any way to associate Marker with an object?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can associate arbitrary object by using [Marker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker)'s [setTag()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) method

```
Marker amarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lat, lng).title("Hello World"));
amarker.setTag(new SomeData());
```

To retrieve data associated with marker, you simply read it using its [getTag()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getTag()) and then cast it to its original type.

```
SomeData adata = (SomeData) amarker.getTag();
```

[More information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#display_additional_information_about_a_marker)

Comment: This is the correct solution. As per documentation about Tag in Marker : "An Object associated with the marker. For example, the Object can contain data about what the marker represents. This is easier than storing a separate Map<Marker, Object>. "

Comment: Correct solution as of Play Services 9.4

Comment: This is the RIGHT solution!

Comment: That's great that after 4 years they've implemented this out-of-the-box =)

Answer (score 54):

I reckon this callback was not very thoroughly though by the Android team, but, it's what we have.

Whenever you call `mMap.addMarker();` it returns the generated marker. You can then use a HashMap or some other data holder structure to remember it.

```
// Create the hash map on the beginning
WeakHashMap <Marker, Object> haspMap = new WeakHashMap <Marker, Object>();


// whenever adding your marker
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lat, lng).title("Hello World").icon(icon_bmp));
haspMap.put(m, your_data);
```

Comment: I recommend `WeakHashMap`, so when a `Marker` gets garbage-collected, so will its associated `WeakHashMap` entry and `Object` value. But, yes, unfortunately this seems to be the only option at present.

Comment: makes sense to me. I edited my answer to be WeakHashMap. Is that ok?

Comment: bzzzzt, wrong! I had to use an HashMap, otherwise the mapping gets somehow garbage collected.

Comment: The documentation says that marker object may change, so don't use the marker as the key, use m.getId().

Comment: hi @dwery , I can't find that on the documentation. Could you point to a link, please?

Comment: @dwery If you do so, you have no chance to remove the marker because you don't have the reference.

Comment: @CommonsWare unless you use this WeakHashMap throughout the app it is not useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to create a Map whose keys is marker.getId() and the value is our object.

In this way, we wouldn't keep a reference to a Marker in memory, and wouldn't have to worry about garbage collected markers.

Here you can see [more answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713726/maps-api-v2-with-different-marker-actions).