# What's a typical way to identify markers and get the Object associated with it?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm using a map in one of my applications. I'd like to know what's a common/efficient way to get the associated Object of a marker when it is tapped.

What I've been planning to day is something like this:

First, I create an ArrayList of my Objects and a HashMap of those Objects using the markers returned by `mMap.addMarker(...);` as the index.

```
ArrayList<MyObject> items = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
HashMap<Marker, MyObject> markersAndObjects = new HashMap<Marker, MyObject>();
```

Now, I override `onMarkerClick()` like so

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker clickedMarker) {
    // send the object returned by markersAndObjects.get(clickedMarker) for processing
    return false;
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associate an object with Marker (google map v2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054122/associate-an-object-with-marker-google-map-v2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to have a Hash with marker ID and your custom data. The Marker object might change if the activity is killed and restored but the ID will remain the same. You map would look like:

```
HashMap<String, MyObject> markersAndObjects = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
```

Marker objects have a getId() method to get the ID.

[Later Edit]

As of August 2016 there is a new API and HashMap is no longer needed. See
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

Comment: So, is this what I'm supposed to do?    `marker = mMap.addMarker(/* use My_Object variables here */);`    `markersAndObjects.put(marker.getId, My_Object);` I don't understand how the ID will remain the same if the Marker Object will change.

Comment: I actually remembered why getId() is the recommended way. Check getId() description on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker . The code you typed in comment is the right one.

Comment: Note that If you are using ClusterManager and implementing your own ClusterRenderer, you have a ClusterRenderer.getClusterItem(marker) which is returning your item object. http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/clustering/view/DefaultClusterRenderer.html#getClusterItem-Marker-