# Get latitude and longitude on click of Marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting `lat/lng: (19.1972,72.93)` in my String using

`String position=String.valueOf(marker.getPosition());`

how to get only latitude and longitude, I don't want to use split

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can I get latitude and longitude directly from marker? or I have to use split only

Comment: you could something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/q/14054122/603744. Since markers are by default final, we can't do setTag, but instead you could use a hashmap<Marker markerObj, ArrayList<LatLongClass>.

Comment: @gaurav check my logic and answer

Comment: @Talha i am passing it in bundle so instead of splitting getting lat long would be better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `marker.getPosition()` you get a `LatLng` object which has a `latitude` and `longitude` properties.

So, you can do:

```
Double latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
Double longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can **split** Lat Long this way

```
String getLatLong="19.1972,72.93";
String[] str_split= getLatLong.split(","); // Split.
String getLat= str_split[0];
String getLong= str_split[1];
```

You should follow **[setOnMarkerClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap)**

```
 your_map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
               // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(arg0); // get Latlong
            // Now you use above logic  
                return true;
            }

        });
```

**Edit**

use  **`marker.getPosition().latitude;`** for better approach .

Comment: I am doing everything on onMarkerClick only

Comment: @gaurav okay okay .Move ahead

Answer (score 1):

You can use (markerClick) instead of click with event. in ts file you can use event.latitude or event.longitude to get them
}