# The this.markers.Put() and this.markers.get() method is throwing the error in my code

Tags: android

Below mentioned code which I have used in my application:

**onKeyEntered:**

```
@Override
public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
   // Add a new marker to the map         
   Marker marker = this.map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new   LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)));
   this.markers.put(key, marker); //Getting the error here
```

**onKeyExited:**

```
@Override
public void onKeyExited(String key) {
   // Remove any old marker 
   Marker marker = this.markers.get(key); //Getting the error here
   if (marker != null) {
      marker.remove();
      this.markers.remove(key);
   }
```

Please suggest what function we can use?

Comment: what is that error?

Comment: @aloke share logcat error

Comment: Please mention details about the errorr, and don't tell me it is NullPointerException

Comment: The error are 'Can't resolve Put' and 'can't resolve Get' in below mentioned specific lines:-Marker marker = this.markers.get(key); this.markers.put(key, marker)

Comment: @AlokeSingh can u post how u have declared and initialized markers?

Comment: Please help me as soon as possible m totally stuck here.

Comment: private Map<String,Marker> markers;   // setup markers
    this.markers = new HashMap<String, Marker>();

Comment: @AlokeSingh Map<String,Marker> is garbage collected use instead of set Tag [see](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker) old [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20126411/3629732)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Associate an object with Marker (google map v2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054122/associate-an-object-with-marker-google-map-v2)