# custom info window adapter with custom data in map v2

Tags: android, infowindow, android-maps-v2

I want to make custom info window adapter in map v2 in android as like below.

[image]

I have seen below link but doesn't get more.

[1](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/using-infowindowadapter-part-1.html),[2,](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html)[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview),

below is my content layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/infocontent_iv_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/infocontent_rl_middle"
        android:layout_below="@id/infocontent_iv_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infocontent_tv_name"
        android:layout_below="@id/infocontent_rl_middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infocontent_tv_type"
        android:layout_below="@id/infocontent_tv_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infocontent_tv_desc"
        android:layout_below="@id/infocontent_tv_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infocontent_tv_addr"
        android:layout_below="@id/infocontent_tv_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So any one help me how can i set data to all views in infowindow adapter?

Comment: just `dialog.dismiss` on x button click and also it close on device back button.

Comment: Hi Girish! I too want to do in the same way as you did. Is it possible your answer little explanatory or any reference. ??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have open dialog `onMarker()` click. and `setContentView(my layout)`.

I have use below code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
        if(arg0.getSnippet() == null){
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
            return true;
        }
        //arg0.showInfoWindow();
        final DataClass data = myMapData.get(arg0);
        final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //d.setTitle("Select");
        d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
        d.setContentView(R.layout.info_content);
        ivPhoto = (ImageView)d.findViewById(R.id.infocontent_iv_image);
        AddImageOnWindow executeDownload = new AddImageOnWindow();
        final LatLng l = arg0.getPosition();
        executeDownload.execute(l);
        TextView tvName = (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.infocontent_tv_name);
        tvName.setText(data.getPlaceName());

        TextView tvType = (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.infocontent_tv_type);
        tvType.setText("("+data.getPlaceType()+")");

        TextView tvDesc = (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.infocontent_tv_desc);
        tvDesc.setText(data.getPlaceDesc());

        TextView tvAddr = (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.infocontent_tv_addr);
        tvAddr.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.getPlaceAddr()));

d.show();
return true;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer a little please?

Comment: I have not open bubble. I have open dialog on marker click event and put buttons in dialog.

Comment: @GirishBhutiya how do you make the dialog to point to top of the marker? (instead of pop up arbitrarily), tks.

Comment: @GirishBhutiya is this Dialog exactly point to the marker position like InfoWindow?

Comment: I like this solution better, because offers total control over appearance. Also, you can add buttons and other controls. I don't think screen position is so important: the dialog will cover most of the screen, anyway, and the user knows where he tapped.

Comment: @GirishBhutiya can you share AddImageOnWindow class?

Comment: @NewBee It just download image from internet nothing else.

Comment: This is a great solution, however, I would like to show the dialog above the marker. Is it possible?

Answer (score 73):

Try this

***windowlayout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lng"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();

    // Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map
    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.windowlayout, null);

            // Getting the position from the marker
            LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

            // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
            TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

            // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
            TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

            // Setting the latitude
            tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);

            // Setting the longitude
            tvLng.setText("Longitude:"+ latLng.longitude);

            // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
            return v;

        }
    });

    // Adding and showing marker while touching the GoogleMap
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
            // Clears any existing markers from the GoogleMap
            googleMap.clear();

            // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions to set position
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting position on the MarkerOptions
            markerOptions.position(arg0);

            // Animating to the currently touched position
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arg0));

            // Adding marker on the GoogleMap
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Showing InfoWindow on the GoogleMap
            marker.showInfoWindow();

        }
    });

}
}
```

In this way you can create custom Layout and achieve the way you want to do.

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I have add my layout file of infowindow adapter. So can you help me how can i set data to all views?

Comment: What do you mean by all views?? View will be one,data will be different??

Comment: ya but I have 4 textview and one imageview so can i set value to all.

Comment: through this method i will get only two string(title & snippet) but how can i set value to other textviews & imageView and image view has dynamic image according to marker clicked.

Comment: Just need to apply the logic. Take a loop and add markers along with the position and same way to show the contents

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713726/maps-api-v2-with-different-marker-actions

Comment: Thanks it work fine. But do you know how can i add buttons in infowindow?

Comment: @droiddev i have two pin for different location, for one pin i set custom infowindow and for other pin i want to set default infowindow. is it possible?

Comment: But if I put the buttons inside the infowindow then the buttons wont accept the clicks. Buttons wont be live. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @CodeWord Have a look at this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events

Comment: Can I add a custom info window to the map marker and not the whole map? Associating the custom adapter with the map and not the map marker seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @AndrewS didn't get it

Comment: @droid_dev: Here you add your custom addapter to the google map with  googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter()......). I have created a separate implementation of the InfoWindowAdapter interface as it's own file. I don't want to set this interface on the whole map as you have done but on each map marker. That way different map markers can have different  adapters and this different functionality.

Comment: use loop to add different marker and its info window

Comment: see this for better idea http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2014/04/20/android-working-with-google-maps-v2-and-custom-markers

Comment: I do not get how a loop will help. I saw that example, but a map can have only one InfoWindowAdapter. I think I've just worked it out, you do not need a loop at all. The methods of the interface have the marker they are associated with as a parameter. It's this that can be used to dynamically choose a layout in the adapter. Thanks for replying so fast.

Comment: error for the line  googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();  Can't resolve getMap()