# Layout over android map

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay

Is there a way, to add some kind of overlay over the google map in witch i will show new layout with informations about the marker, layout should not be full screen.

I need to display informations about a marker on the map, i wanted it to be something like on googles earth when you go over a marker and you see a new frame that shows you picture and some text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15091202/1278196

Comment: Dear, there are lot many articles already exists for the same. Have you tried at least for doing R&D?