# set InfoWindowAdapter show information only for first marker clicked

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, infowindow

So, I have set `infowindowadapter` for my Google map, but the problem is that when I click on the first marker, it shows the information correctly, but when I hit the second marker it shows information from the first one, so `infowindowadapter` doesn't refresh.

Can someone tell me why that it and how to fix it?

I was following this post to set `infowindowadapter`:

[custom info window adapter with custom data in map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090148/custom-info-window-adapter-with-custom-data-in-map-v2/15091202#15091202)

EDIT:

```
    new getMarkers().execute();

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return false;
        }
    });
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_details_on_map,null);

            date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtMarkerDate);
            comment = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtMarkerComment);
            image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivMarkerPicture);

            MyMarkerInfo mmi = markerMap.get(marker.getId());
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",mmi.getId()));

            MarkerDetails mDetails = new JSONAdapter().getMarkerDetails(params);
            date.setText(mDetails.getDate());
            comment.setText(mDetails.getComment());

            new getPicture().execute(mDetails.getImageUrl());
            return view;
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Just now i tryed to setOnMarkerClickListner and in it i call marker.showinfowindow(), hoping that it will call getInfoContent again but nothing have changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my code for exactly the same operation:

```
    // Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();

                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                title.setText(args.getTitle());

                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                    {
                        if (SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation!=null)
                        {   
                            if (String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) &&
                                    String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This your current location, navigation is not needed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FlurryAgent.onEvent("Start navigation window was clicked from daily map");
                                tasksRepository = SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository();
                                for (Task tmptask : tasksRepository)
                                {
                                    String tempTaskLat = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude());
                                    String tempTaskLng = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLongtitude());

                                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8));

                                    if (tempTaskLat.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) && tempTaskLng.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                                    {  
                                        task = tmptask;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                /*
                                findDirections(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude(),
                                               SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude(),
                                               clickMarkerLatLng.latitude, clickMarkerLatLng.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );
                                */
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,RoadDirectionsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location could not be found,\nNavigation is not possible.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;

            }
        });
```

My guess would be that your are getting other markers information the wrong way. try to compare between my method and yours, and try to log the process to see that you are passing the right Id and getting the right info.

Comment: You were right. My co worker have made mistake in his php script returning me only defined id in his script and not getting my request id xD

Ty for your help, i get u vote up as soon as i get enough reputation

Cheers

Comment: Great you found your problem, have a nice coding : )