# Aligning the text in Google Maps Marker snippet

Tags: android, google-maps, line-breaks, marker, text-align

I want the string in my snippet to be aligned to the center.

Also, line breakers (\n) in the snippet are converted to spaces, is there a way to insert line breakers?

My relevant code:

```
GoogleMap map = ...
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos)
        .title("title")
        .snippet("body \n and mind");
```

Thanks

Comment: You could define your own [InfoWindowAdapter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter). Look at the [Google Maps Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code) where you can find a MarkerDemoActivity.java where they create a CustomInfoWindowAdapter and assign a custom .xml file to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using some examples, as well as answers from: [custom info window adapter with custom data in map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090148/custom-info-window-adapter-with-custom-data-in-map-v2), I've come across the following solution:

marker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker, null);

            TextView info= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info);

            info.setText(marker.getPosition().toString());

            return v;
        }
    });
```