# centre title in google map app

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to android develop. I have a google map app and I am thinking to centre the title of the map. 
[image]

I find the title "Hi!" is defined in string.xml as

```
 <string name="title_activity_maps">Hi!</string>
```

But I cannot find it in my layout. So I'm not sure where I can put code to centre this title. Here is my activity_maps.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_above="@+id/latlongLocation" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latlongLocation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/reminder"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783227/aligning-the-text-in-google-maps-marker-snippet

Comment: Hi. I read it. I don't think this works...