# android: how to set button on click listener on custom infoWindow using google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to set `button` `onClick` on custom `infoWindow` using `Google Map` V2 and below is my complete code but not working properly.

here is my MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ViewGroup infoWindow;
private TextView infoTitle;
private TextView infoSnippet;
private Button infoButton;
private OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener infoButtonListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
    final GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();

    mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));

    this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
    this.infoTitle = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
    this.infoSnippet = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
    this.infoButton = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button);

    this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
    {
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle() + "'s button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    this.infoButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);

    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
            infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
            infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
            infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);
            mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
            return infoWindow;
        }
    });

    // Let's add a couple of markers
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Prague")
            .snippet("Czech Republic")
            .position(new LatLng(50.08, 14.43)));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Paris")
            .snippet("France")
            .position(new LatLng(48.86,2.33)));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("London")
            .snippet("United Kingdom")
            .position(new LatLng(51.51,-0.1)));
}

public static int getPixelsFromDp(Context context, float dp) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int)(dp * scale + 0.5f);

}
```

and below is my activity_main

```
<com.circlegate.tt.cg.an.lib.map.MapWrapperLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

// here is MapWrapperLayout.

```
public class MapWrapperLayout extends RelativeLayout {
private GoogleMap map;
private int bottomOffsetPixels;
private Marker marker;
private View infoWindow;

public MapWrapperLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public MapWrapperLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public MapWrapperLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
public void init(GoogleMap map, int bottomOffsetPixels) {
    this.map = map;
    this.bottomOffsetPixels = bottomOffsetPixels;
}
public void setMarkerWithInfoWindow(Marker marker, View infoWindow) {
    this.marker = marker;
    this.infoWindow = infoWindow;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean ret = false;
    // Make sure that the infoWindow is shown and we have all the needed references
    if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown() && map != null && infoWindow != null) {

        Point point = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
        MotionEvent copyEv = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        copyEv.offsetLocation(
                -point.x + (infoWindow.getWidth() / 2),
                -point.y + infoWindow.getHeight() + bottomOffsetPixels);

        ret = infoWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(copyEv);
    }
    return ret || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

// and here is OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener

```
        public abstract class OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener 
    {
        private final View view;
        private final Drawable bgDrawableNormal;
        private final Drawable bgDrawablePressed;
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();
        private Marker marker;
        private boolean pressed = false;

        public OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(View view, Drawable bgDrawableNormal, Drawable bgDrawablePressed) {
            this.view = view;
            this.bgDrawableNormal = bgDrawableNormal;
            this.bgDrawablePressed = bgDrawablePressed;
        }
        public void setMarker(Marker marker) {
            this.marker = marker;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View vv, MotionEvent event) {
            if (0 <= event.getX() && event.getX() <= view.getWidth() &&
                    0 <= event.getY() && event.getY() <= view.getHeight())
            {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: startPress(); break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: handler.postDelayed(confirmClickRunnable, 150); break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: endPress(); break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }
            else {
                endPress();
            }
            return false;
        }
        private void startPress() {
            if (!pressed) {
                pressed = true;
                handler.removeCallbacks(confirmClickRunnable);
                view.setBackground(bgDrawablePressed);
                if (marker != null)
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
        }
        private boolean endPress() {
            if (pressed) {
                this.pressed = false;
                handler.removeCallbacks(confirmClickRunnable);
                view.setBackground(bgDrawableNormal);
                if (marker != null)
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        private final Runnable confirmClickRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (endPress()) {
                    onClickConfirmed(view, marker);
                }
            }
        };
        protected abstract void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible because view on map is work as an image so whole click on custom window is possible but each button click  is not possible as per Google Docs.

Comment: try this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567563/google-map-v2-custom-infowindow-with-two-clickable-buttons-or-imageview

Answer (score 0):

Directly we can't able to do this,try to use this library 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid)