# InfoWindow Content Click is not working for layouts In Android

Tags: android

I'm using google map in my application ,when I click the marker info-window is opened again I want to click the info-window layout but its not working for layouts.If I give click listener for button means its working.Please help me to fix this issue.

Activity:

```
public class SampleFragment1 extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private ViewGroup infoWindow;
    private TextView infoTitle;
    private TextView infoSnippet,userNameTV,loggedLabel,userLastNameTV,time,distance,tasks;
    private Button infoButton, infoButton2;
    private OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener infoButtonListener;
    LinearLayout markerlay;
  GoogleMap mMap;
    public void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    private MapView mapView;

    private MarkerOptions mMarker;

    MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.con_fragment_google, container, false);
       mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
      mapView = (MapView)view. findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        //  getContext().startService(new Intent(getContext(),GPSTracker.class));
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
 mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }



    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    // to get current latitude and longitude
    // storing the updated latitde and longitude when user moving and reach destination
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

       mapWrapperLayout.init(mMap, getPixelsFromDp(getContext(), 39 + 20));

        // We want to reuse the info window for all the markers,
        // so let's create only one class member instance
        this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_widow_layout, null);
        this.infoTitle = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.nametv);
        this.infoSnippet = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.addressTv);
        this.infoButton = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.clinicType);

        // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
        // so it shows up
        this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoTitle
        ) //btn_default_pressed_holo_light
        {
            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
                // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), marker.getTitle() + "'s button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        this.infoTitle.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);


        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
                infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

                // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow references
                // to the MapWrapperLayout
                mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                return infoWindow;
            }
        });

        // Let's add a couple of markers


    }

    public static int getPixelsFromDp(Context context, float dp) {
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Note:Here I give click listener for textview ,the textview present inside the layout.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567563/google-map-v2-custom-infowindow-with-two-clickable-buttons-or-imageview

Comment: in that link also they give for button alone.for layouts clickable is not working

Comment: For which layout you are trying for