# Is it possible add an action to a infoWindow in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps

I am developing activity with a map, and markers, and I want to add several actions for each marker, like calculate route or call to a phone, it is possible to add an action like in the notifications?

like this [image]

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567563/google-map-v2-custom-infowindow-with-two-clickable-buttons-or-imageview

Comment: finally I found this: github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
implements OnMarkerClickListener
```

{
    private Marker myMarker;

```
private void setUpMap()
{
    .......
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("My Spot")
                .snippet("This is my spot!")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
    ......
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    if (marker.equals(myMarker)) 
    {
        //handle click here
    }
}
```

}

hope this code helpful

Comment: This doesn't work, because i want add actions inside the infowindow.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES: Why did you accept this answer, since it does not answer your question?